# Foreign Key Will Not Add

Tags: mysql

A foreign key will just not add in mySQL.

I checked the parent is a primary key. The child is indexed.  They are both INT.

Here's the code, which strangely worked earlier, there are three previous relationships defined.

I got this from S.O.

ALTER TABLE domains
  ADD CONSTRAINT ftttttttt
  FOREIGN KEY (fast_id) 
  REFERENCES fasttrans(fast_id);

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Andre, this is the error:#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`943918_domainSpin88`.`#sql-459_1f68ad`, CONSTRAINT `ftttttttt` FOREIGN KEY (`fast_id`) REFERENCES `fasttrans` (`fast_id`)) // Best regards and thanks,

Comment: The error message is telling you that there's a row in `domains` with a fast_id that does not exist in `fasttrans`, therefore the foreign key cannot be created. `SELECT * FROM domains d WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fasttrans ft WHERE d.fast_id = ft.fast_id)` should tell you which rows are invalid.

Comment: Genius, thanks @AndreFeijo!

Comment: Phew my first ever question on S.O.!